# Flutter global websocket connection

Tags: flutter, websocket, state-management

Is it good practice to keep one global websocket connection in mobile apps, or do I need to use separate one on each page? I am using Clean Architecture with get_it dependency injector, so I want to inject my websocket connection inside remote data source, but the problem arises when I want to listen from the stream: When I go on page that wants websocket connection, go back and go to that page, I got "Stream has already been listened to" exception.

P.S using web_socket_channel pub dev package

What do I need to do?

One of my thoughts was to use factory instead of singleton for websocket connection, but I got into issue that remote data source and my widget got different websocket connections, and remote data source one got closed for some reason. Also global websocket connection got closed when idle, event with ping interval.

Comment: Trying to share a global connection in web_socket_channel plugin. Please share your thought and guidance for this approach.

We have around 40 screens through out application, need to listen in entire application.

Please guide me.

Comment: @RajeshMP advice I got from one of my teachers is to use socket.io, as it handles all the routine stuff of websockets